# Need to exclude @LastModifiedBy field from Spring Data JPA save comparison

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with a field annotated with @LastModifiedBy. This is an audit field. Let us say the entity has 5 other data related fields. The JPA save method updates the record in the table even if only @LastModifiedBy has changed and none of the other 5 fields have changed and this is not what I want.

I would expect the 'save' method to compare the old and new values of the data related fields, detect if something has changed and issue an update to the DB after populating the field annotated with @LastModifiedBy, but the save method is including the audit field in the comparison and that is causing an unnecessary DB update. In addition, I'm losing the audit trail in the DB and that is not acceptable.

I'm forced to compare all the data related fields and call the 'save' method only if something has changed in order to solve the above issue.

Is there a way to exclude the audit columns from the comparison done by the 'save' method?

```
//This method is in the service class
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public void updateUser(....)
{
        User user = userRepo.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new User_Not_Found_Exception("User with id: " +             userId + " not found"));

        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        ...
//I'm not setting lastUpdatedUserId here
        userRepo.save(user);

}

@Entity
@Table(name="usr")
@DynamicUpdate
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "usr_id")
    private Integer userId;
    
    @Column(name = "usr_frst_nm")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "usr_lst_nm")
    private String lastName;
    
    ....    
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "lst_updtd_usr_id")
    private Integer lastUpdatedUserId;
    ...

}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef="auditorP")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    AuditorAware<Integer> auditorP() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }

}

public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Integer> {
    
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    
    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> getCurrentAuditor() {
        
        //This happens during a JPA life cycle event and we are not allowed to 
        //use a JPA repository or EntityManager here. Hence I could not use
        //UserRepository here.     
        return Optional.of(getLoginUserId());
    }
    
    private Integer getLoginUserId()
    {
        return (Integer) request.getAttribute("loginUserId");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you manually updating the last modified by field or letting JPA update it using an AuditorAware implementation?

Comment: Lee - I'm using an AuditorAware implemenation. I had to override the getCurrentAuditor method to get a userid from the database based on the emailid of the logged in user. I'm getting the emailid from the authentication object.

Comment: Are you explicitly calling save() or are you letting a ```@Transactional``` annotated method manage updating entities that have changed? It might help if you show the code in question.

Comment: Yes, I'm explicitly calling save(). I have updated the question with a snippet of the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have verified this is the default behavior after the created/modified fields have been set. If they are null, legacy data that wasn't being audited at the time, then the update does not occur. I can see an argument both ways for what you are asking for and what is implemented. I don't see a way to way to override this behavior. It looks like you need a more robust auditing framework such as [Envers](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-envers).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lee. I'm surprised since most of the examples that I see online call save() without comparing the data related fields. So everybody who is using it this way is losing the audit trail and I don't know how many people are aware of it. In my situation, I have a HTML form mapped to 3 entities in the DB. Even if 1 field changes on the form, I submit a request to the server. So the server ends up updating all 3 entities due to the behaviour of the save method.  I will look into Envers and see if it helps. Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: With Envers you have more of a true audit trail, how changes were made over time. There is overhead with maintaining the audit trail but you rarely get something at no cost.

Comment: Take a look at [this] (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1481) discussion also.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. Will surely take a look.

Comment: If none of these work for you, you can always hook into the JPA ```@PrePersist``` and ```@PreUpdate``` annotations. Put these and your attributes in a base class and manage basic auditing yourself. See [this](https://medium.com/@rameshbabu1213745/understanding-jpa-annotations-prepersist-and-preupdate-6949fe3a6125) for more info.

Comment: I looked into this a little more day. What I noticed is that the behaviour that I experienced is with an entity that has a many to many relationship. If you see the code that I shared, it's a user entity and it has a many to many relationship with roles. If I comment out  user.setRoles(roles) and then call userRepo.save(user), the user table does not get updated if nothing has changed.   If the line is not commented out, then JPA deletes all the records in the join table and recreates them(even if none of the roles have changed). It then updates the user table and the audit column changes.

Comment: So it appears that JPA thinks that the child table(join table in this case) has been updated and hence it needs to update the audit columns on the parent table(user in this case) even if nothing has changed on the parent table.  I tested this with another entity that has a many to many relationship with language and I saw the same behaviour. If we don't want the audit columns on the parent to be updated since nothing has changed on the parent, then we need to explicitly compare the data related fields before calling save() on the parent.

Comment: I was not aware that the many to many relationship was causing the behavior that I experienced else I would have included it in the code that I shared.  I'm OK if the audit columns on the User table get updated when 1 or more roles  associated to the user change. The issue is that JPA deletes all records in the join table and recreates them even if none of the roles change. In addition, it updates the audit columns on the user. I think I need to change the many to many to 1:many & many:1 and this will solve the issue. Will try it out.

Comment: I replaced the many to many relationship as mentioned in the comment above and the audit column is working as expected. Lee - You mentioned that you also tested it and experienced the same behavior. Did your entity also have a many to many relationship? If yes, that will confirm my findings.

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: What version of spring data jpa are you using? I'm using 3.2.2 and this is the behaviour i'm seeing. I tested it with 2-3 entities and they are all behaving the same way.

Comment: Same version as you. Does the parent entity still get updated when no changes are made?

Comment: Use case 1: Parent entity does not have a many to many relationship. It can have any other relationship like one to one or one to many -> Parent entity does not get updated if no changes were made to the Parent.                                     Use case 2: Parent entity has a many to many relationship    -> Parent entity gets updated even if no changes were made to the Parent. This is regardless of whether changes were made OR NOT made to the many to many relationship.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment in order to make the verbiage more clear. Do you have any audit columns other than @LastModifiedBy? If yes, can you check if they are being set correctly in Spring thru the AuditorAware implementation? I have a lastUpdatedDateTime field, but that is getting populated by the DB and not thru Java.  I'm tyring to find out what could be the difference between your code and mine that is causing the behaviour to be different.